# Alternating background color of nested elements

Tags: html, css, sass

My markup contains a tree structure of same element that looks something like this:

```
<div class="node">
  <div class="node">
    <div class="node" />
  </div>
  <div class="node" />
</div>
```

What I would like to do is to alternate their background colors for each depth. I was able to achieve this by pretty ugly css and was wondering if there is a smarter way. Here is the `naive solution`:

```
.a {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  .a {
    background-color: green;
    .a {
      background-color: red;
      /* etc... */
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're auto-generating this using some script, then you could track it using an iterator variable, like `for(let i = 0; i < ...`. Otherwise, you could just add a class to each child like `odd` and `even`.

Comment: It's a React app and the nodes are components (more or less) but it wouldn't be that simple to carry over the information whether current node should be `odd` or `even` in script.

Comment: Do you know the maximum depth before hand? Is it always 3?

Comment: @AskYous yes that seems to be pretty similar, so it seems that this can't be done with css purely.

Comment: Yeah you can't. If you know the maximum depth, you can write it easily using LESS or SASS, assuming it's not that big. Otherwise, you could write code to generate a new style tag.

Comment: Well I guess that just nesting enough `.a { ... .a{ ... .a { ...` would be sufficient then.

Comment: Do you know what LESS and SASS is? It might make this way easier. They allow nested css and it will generate the CSS for you.

Comment: Well I'm even using SASS in the example so yes :D Can I maybe use some loop or function from SASS to generate the nested classes?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know.

Comment: here is an idea : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52118738/8620333

Answer (score 0):

Use the direct descendent selector

```
// Parent
.a {
  background: red;
}

// Child
.a > .a {
  background: green;
}

// Grandchild
.a > .a > .a {
  background: red;
}
```

```css
.a {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.a > .a {
  background: green;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.a > .a > .a {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm already doing.

Comment: Are you trying to do it more dynamically?

Comment: Yes because the depth is not limited.